# Update value property from JS "string"

Tags: javascript, json

I got this value and I need to update the property application_name to myApp,

i've tried with `JSON.parse` but I got error "unexpected token ' "

this is a short example of the "string" which I got...
Any idea?

```
"'{\"instance_id\":\"71658c8c-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc\",\"application_name\":\"ht10\"}'\r"
```

Comment: remove the trailing `\r` and then parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/rLgsb3p7/

```
{\"instance_id\":\"71658c8c-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc\",\"application_name\":\"ht10\"}
```

Is a json string
try:

```
var v = "'{\"instance_id\":\"71658c8c-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc\",\"application_name\":\"ht10\"}'\r";
v = v.slice(1,v.length-2);
var x = JSON.parse(v);
console.log(x);
```

/r counts as a single character

Comment: Thanks a lot 1+ , last question assume I need to add(at the end) the quotes what is the opposite to v = v.slice(1,v.length-2);? and what do you mean by /r counts as a single character?

Comment: That is a bit beyond the scope of your initial query. just know \r is treated as a single character. [ H ] [ E ] [ L ] [ L ] [ O ] [ \r ]

Comment: if you need to append a string just use v += "appeneded text";

Comment: if you want to re-add your quotes use v = "'" + v + "'";

Answer (score 2):

Your string has an extra set of quotes which is causing JSON.parse to fail. This parses:

```
JSON.parse("{\"instance_id\":\"71658c8c-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc\",\"application_name\":\"ht10\"}")
```

Comment: Thanks but I got it as parameter to function so what should i do in this case?